# How to install nginx 1.9x with HTTP 2 support (1.95 or higher) on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http, ubuntu-15.10

I tried to install the latest nginx version (1.99) on my ubuntu 15.10. I want a nginx version >= 1.95 because I like to have http 2 support.

I followed the instructions I found on the internet for ubuntu 14.04, but which should be the same for ubuntu 15.10 (http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/install-latest-version-nginx-ubuntu-14-10/):

1. Download Nginx repository authentication key:

   ```
   cd /tmp/ && wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
   ```
2. Install the repository key:

   ```
   sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
   ```
3. Create a new repository file for Nginx

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
   ```
4. Then copy and paste the lines below into the file and save it ("wily" is the Ubuntu codename for my 15.10 ubuntu version)

   ```
   deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ wily nginx
   deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ wily nginx
   ```

But when I finally ran the command:

```
apt-get install nginx
```

I got the following error:

```
nginx : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is to be installed
         Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1e-2+deb7u17 is to be installed
```

So how can I solve this issue? Is there any way I can install nginx 1.99 (or 1.95) on my Ubuntu server?

Comment: Are you sure you're on Ubuntu 15.10? What other apt sources do you have configured?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Nginx mainline PPA: https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/development.

You can run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/development` to set it up.